# Do I need to check if keys exist before adding new values to it in multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php

I remember writing code a long time ago like seen below. Where you check each key before adding value to it in multidimensional arrays:

```
$transactions = [];

if (!isset($transactions[$account])) {
    $transactions[$account] = [];
}

if (!$transactions[$account]['cards'])) {
    $transactions[$account]['cards'] = [];
}

$transactions[$account]["cards"][] = $card;
```

but recently I noticed that I have started writing this:

```
$transactions = [];

$transactions[$account]["cards"][] = $card;
```

and everything seems to work just fine without declaring those arrays beforehand.

Comment: If you dont check, its possible to overwrite an existing occurance **`there can be only one`** but if you cannot get a duplicate key, you dont need to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PHP will implicitly create intermediate arrays on assignment (and only on assignment):

> If [the array] doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an
>   alternative way to create an array. This practice is however
>   discouraged because if [the array] already contains some value (e.g. string
>   from request variable) then this value will stay in the place and `[]`
>   may actually stand for string access operator. It is always better to
>   initialize a variable by a direct assignment.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

So, yes, it works and is explicitly supported, as long as you're sure about your array structures and you're not accidentally using `[...]` to access a string index instead of the array you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to check when you create the Multi dimensional or any **Array**.
But you need to check, when you want to **Update** or **Delete** the array.

Examle:

```
$transactions[$account]["cards"][] = $card;
// you dont need to check here.

$transactions[$account]["cards"][] = 343; // This may not work
// When you want to update it, you need to check

if(isset($transactions[$account]["cards"]))
    $transactions[$account]["cards"] = 343;
// The above condition helps you in not breaking the script,
//if you want to assign to an array which is not created.
```

Good Luck!